# Do all the scripts (prebuild, build, postbuild) run on server automatically after deploying the Node JS app on any web host with Node JS support?

Tags: node.js, package.json

The content of the **package.json** file of a node JS project is shown below. In this file three scripts are specified (prebuild, build, postbuild). If I deploy the node app to **any** web host that supports node JS, will all the three scripts run automatically on the server after deploying?

```
{
    "name": "npm-scripts-example",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "npm scripts example",
    "scripts": {
      "prebuild": "echo I run before the build script",
      "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack",
      "postbuild": "echo I run after the build script"
    }
}
```

Comment: No, the will run when you call `npm run build`

Comment: Then only "npm start" will run automatically on any node server, right? @depirscher

Comment: Why would you suppose anything will run automatically? That totally depends on how the server is configured ...

Comment: Because I want build and start scripts to run on server automatically after deploying my app to make the app active. @derpirscher